# CSS selector decendant not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

i'm using decendant but the **h1 p** doesn't work. what wrong with type selector

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>  
            <style>
        h1 p{
                color:blue; 
            }


            </style>
    </head>
    <body>  <h1>My first html5 & CSS3 page</h1>

    <p>The versions of SID and CRUD distributed with SQL Essential Training do not work with PHP warnings enabled. This was fixed before MySQL Essential Training was recorded. The 1.3 version here is the fixed version. (If you have the files from MySQL Essential Training,you already have this.) </p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS descendants need the child element (`p`) to be *inside* the parent element (`h1`).

Like:

```
<h1> <p>I'm inside h1</p> </h1>
```

That is not the case here, so this won't work. What you need is the next-sibling selector `+` or `~` which select the single following tag or all the following tags.

So, for example:

```
h1 + p {color:blue;}
```

will do the following:

```
<h1>Example header</h1>
<p>This paragraph is blue.</p>
<p>This paragraph is the default color</p>
```

And:

```
h1 ~ p {color:blue;}
```

Will do:

```
<h1>Example header</h1>
<p>This paragraph is blue.</p>
<p>This paragraph is also blue.</p>
```

In the case you have multiple paragraphs after your header, I suggest using the latter.

If you want to only colour the paragraphs after the `<h1>`, but **not** after the following `<h2>`, you can do this:

```
h1 ~ p {color:blue;}
h1 ~ h2 ~ p {color:inherit;}
```

That will result in the following:

```
<h1>Example level 1 header</h1>
<p>This paragraph is blue.</p>
<p>This paragraph is also blue.</p>
<h2>Example level 2 header</h2>
<p>This paragraph is placed after the level 2 header, so it's not blue anymore.</p>
```

The `inherit` value will make the paragraphs take the colour that was defined on the parent elements (so the default value), which overrides the blue colour.

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsbin.com/OYixaYof/1/). You can remove the second line of CSS if you don't want to prevent the paragraphs after the level 2 header from being blue.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a a child element. You can use the [General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) for this case:

CSS

```
h1 ~ p{
  color:blue; 
}
```

HTML

```
<h1>My first html5 & CSS3 page</h1>
<p>The versions of SID and CRUD ...</p>
```

Or use a real parent element, for example:

CSS

```
.parent p{
  color:blue; 
}
```

HTML

```
<h1>My first html5 & CSS3 page</h1>
<div class="parent">
  <p>The versions of SID and CRUD ...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, yes please, edit it so i know what should i normally do :) thanks!

Comment: Just keep the essential parts. +1 keep answer